# Punteros dentro de Registro en C - ABM

Tags: c, punteros

Estoy haciendo un programa en C con registros, el objetivo es cargar vectores y mostrarlos, para ambas cosas utilizo el ciclo for, pero al utilizar un puntero (llamado cant) el programa no me muestra correctamenta el vector. Quisiera saber como solucionarlo y cual es el error que estoy cometiendo. Gracias!

Acá creo los Typedef:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX_GASTOS 10
void menu();
typedef struct gastos{
    int importe;
    char conceptos[50];
}t_gastos;
typedef struct departamentos{
    int num_depto;
    char nombre[50];
    int num_piso;
    char letra_depto[1];
    int *cant;
    t_gastos gastos[10];
}t_departamentos;
```

Despues el main:

```
int main()
{
  int continuar=0;
  int cant_deptos=0;
  int x=0,z=0;
  t_departamentos depto[30];
  do{
    menu();
    scanf("%d",&continuar);
    switch (continuar) {
      case 1: x=cargar(depto);
      break;
      case 2:z=mostrarVec(depto);
      break;
      case 4:printf("Fin del programa\n");
      break;
      default:printf("Error,Opción incorrecta\n");
      break;
    }
  }while(continuar!=4);
    return 0;
}
```

acá es donde aplico las funciones de carga:

```
int cargar(t_departamentos depto[], int *cant){
  int i;
  int cont=1;
  do {
    for (i=0;i<*cant;i++){
        printf("\n----------------------Carga de datos----------------------\n");
        printf("Ingrese el Numero de departamento\n");
        scanf("%d",&depto[i].num_depto);
        getchar();
        printf("Ingrese nombre y apellido del propietario\n");
        gets(depto[i].nombre);
        printf("Ingrese el piso del departamento\n");
        scanf("%d",&depto[i].num_piso);
        getchar();
        printf("Ingrese la letra del departamento\n");
        gets(depto[i].letra_depto);
        //printf("Ingrese el concepto\n");
        //gets(depto[i].gastos.concepto);
        //printf("Ingrese el impote\n");
        //scanf("%d",&depto[i].gastos.importe);
    }
    printf("Desea continuar? 1 si 0 no\n");
    scanf("%d",&cont);
  }while(cont!=0);
}
```

y por ultimo al funcion de muestra del vector, (tambien está la funcion del menu pero no es importante):

```
void mostrarVec(t_departamentos depto[], int *cant){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<*cant;i++){
      printf("APELLIDO\t\tPISO\t\tDEPTO\n%s\t\t\t%d-%s\t\t%d\n\n",depto[i].nombre,depto[i].num_piso,depto[i].letra_depto,depto[i].num_depto);
    }
}
void menu(){
    printf("----------------------Menu----------------------\n");
    printf("1.Cargar vector de departamentos\n");
    printf("2.Generar listado\n");
    printf("3.Consulta por conceptos\n");
    printf("4.Salir\n");
}
```

Comment: ¿Porqué cant es un puntero y no un simple entero?. ¿Cuántos y cuales son los parámetros de la función cargar?¿ De dónde viene cant, o dicho de otra forma, a qué está apuntando?.

Comment: Estás mezclando código de dos ejercicios diferentes. Esto huele a que te han pasado el ejercicio ya hecho  y lo estás modificando para que no parezca el mismo... lo digo básicamente porque ese código **no compila**, luego dificilmente puedes ver que `cant` está funcionando incorrectamente

Comment: Todo el ejercicio lo hice yo desde cero siguiendo las consignas del profesor, pero no logro entender como pasar los valores del "cant" de una función a otra, sin usar un puntero, y no se como corregirlo. Los parámetros que paso en "cant" sería el largo del vector, osea la cantidad de elementos que se guardan en el vector y mostrarlos en otra función

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Todo el código es erróneo, ni siquiera compila. Tus errores, por orden de aparición:

1. Defines `cant_deptos` y no la usas en todo el `main`.
2. Defines `x` y `z` para capturar los retornos de `cargar` y `mostrarVec` pero no usas el valor capturado en todo el `main`.
3. `cargar` está definida para recibir dos parámetros, pero le pasas sólo uno. Suponiendo que fuese posible compilar eso, dado que en la llamada no pasas el segundo parámetro, el puntero `cant` tendrá un valor indeterminado y acceder al contenido del mismo será [comportamiento indefinido](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comportamiento_indefinido).
4. `cargar` está definida para devolver un entero (`int`), pero finaliza sin devolver nada.
5. `mostrarVec` está definida para recibir dos parámetros, pero le pasas sólo uno. Suponiendo que fuese posible compilar eso, dado que en la llamada no pasas el segundo parámetro, el puntero `cant` tendrá un valor indeterminado y acceder al contenido del mismo será [comportamiento indefinido](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comportamiento_indefinido).
6. `mostrarVec` está definida para devolver un entero (`int`), pero finaliza sin devolver nada.

Estás cometiendo todos esos errores, pero si tuviera que señalar sólo uno diría que tu error es que no entiendes el código, yo volvería a empezar el código desde el principio.